# Update user's email in Orchard

Tags: database, orchardcms, insert-update

I want to allow users to update their email, so I have controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeEmail(string newEmail) {
    IUser user = _services.WorkContext.CurrentUser;
    if (!user.Is<UserPart>())
        throw new InvalidCastException();

    var userRecord = user.As<UserPart>().Record;
    userRecord.Email = newEmail;
    return null;
}
```

Everything builds and runs OK except that the database doesn't update new email.
What should I do ?
Thanks all !

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are trying to update the Record directly instead of setting the value of the Part and letting Orchard save your changes:

```
user.As<UserPart>().Email = newEmail;
```

Your change will be automatically committed to the db at the end of the request.

As a side note the reason your changes are not saving is that when you update a record you need explicitly update it using an injected repository e.g. `_userRepository.Update(user.Record)` where _userRepository is an injected `IRepository<UserPartRecord>`, but just updating the part is the way to go.